# Git credential in Mobaxterm terminal

Tags: linux, windows, git

I am using mobaxterm local terminal. I want to use git commands. It's working except for credentials:

```
 ➤ git pull
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/lib/ssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have try settings credential, but nothing works:

```
    [05/03/2018 08:03.49]  ~/dsf
    [sylvain.auger-leger.vbw-sau-13] ➤ git git config --global credential.helper cache
                                                                                                                                                                                                            ✔


[05/03/2018 08:04.29]  ~/dsf
[sylvain.auger-leger.vbw-sau-13] ➤ git config --global credential.helper cache
                                                                                                                                                                                                        ✔

[05/03/2018 08:04.30]  ~/dsf
[sylvain.auger-leger.vbw-sau-13] ➤ git config --global credential.helper 'store --file ~/.my-credentials'
                                                                                                                                                                                                        ✔
```

Answer (score 0):

A git credential helper would help for https credential caching, not ssh.

Check first if your remote URL is an SSH one:

```
git remote -v
```

If it is (`ssh://` or `git@xxx:user/repo`) then:

- check if you have a public/private ssh key in `~/.ssh`
- or switch to https if possible:

  ```
  git remote set-url origin https://url/remote/repo
  ```

Comment: Check also your Mobaxterm installation: https://superuser.com/a/1071180/141